# How to enable PhpStorm autocompletion on space?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I configure PhpStorm to autocomplete highlighted entry on keys like *space*, ()[],; and other relevant keys? Right now autocompletion only works with keys like *Enter*, *Tab*, and dash (-).

I know there is an option `Editor > General > Code Completion > "Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys"`. But it seems like toggling it does not have the effect I want. So far I found out it only enables autocompletion additionally by dash (-), but not *space* or brackets.

For example, if I have this view:
[image]
*Wanted* behaviour after I press space (highlighted entry insertion):
[image]
*Current* behaviour after I press space (it just prints space):
[image]

I think what I want is default behavior Visual Studio and I really like it, enables faster typing and less *Enter* presses. But can't figure out how to configure PhpStorm the same way.

Comment: Looks like, there is no way to enable space for completion, however, from what I have noticed, space is working fine after you press "ctrl+space" first.

Comment: Yep, can confirm that it works. But it does not enable faster typing :/